# Why is $c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}$?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, refraction, maxwell-equations, dielectric

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate but I didn't find my answer. I'm currently studying maxwell's equations and I know that by comparing the wave equation for either the magnetic or the electric field

\begin{equation}
   \Delta \vec{B} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 \vec{B}}{\partial t^2}.
\end{equation}

By comparing this to the general wave equation it is concluded that

\begin{equation}
  c =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}
\end{equation}

But that already assumes that my wave travels at the speed of light. How do I know that the EM wave propagates at $c$?

Comment: Short answer: Maxwell's equations and experiment.

Comment: "How do I know that the EM wave propagates at c". By definition. $c$ is the symbol used to denote the speed of EM waves. Its value is then measured experimentally.

Comment: you need to get an equation with a single field $\vec{E}$, $\vec{H}$ which is the wave equation and which has solution of propagating waves with the speed of light

Comment: Maxwell's equations give rise to the wave equation and the wave equation predicts that light travels with speed ${1\over\sqrt{\mu_0\epsilon_0}}$. Experiment then affirms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wave travelling with speed $v$ satisfies the equation
$$
\partial_t^2 \phi (t,\vec{x}) = v^2 \nabla^2 \phi (t,\vec{x}) .
$$
Comparing this to Maxwell's equation, we see that the speed at which light travels is given by
$$
c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}.
$$
That this same speed is the maximum allowed speed is an insight by Einstein. That does not automatically follow from Maxwell's equations.

Comment: While it is an insight from Einstein, it partially comes from the question, with respect to which frame should I measure this speed if EM waves travel in vacuum? Frame of the source? Earth's frame? The answer is all the frames.

Comment: Yes, Lorent, Poincare and Einstein were the first to start providing really good answers to the questions that arose.

Comment: @Mauricio And, if I may add to that,  one should be *mighty* uncomfortable with that answer.   That answer should make no sense.  It went against all intuition, but its the way the experimental evidence worked out.  This lead to relativity, which uproots a lot of things we thought were intuitive but turned out not to be true statements about our universe.

Comment: @CortAmmon Agree that was Einstein's part.

Comment: @Mauricio That's right, a plane wave (or single photon, take your pick) forgets about its source and doesn't have a frequency/wavelength (energy/momentum)...that depends in the observers frame. The Lorentz scalars are: $c$, phase ($k^{\mu}x_{\mu}$), and the number of photons. I suppose helicity, too, but I haven't transformed $\epsilon_{\mu}$ much, in spite of a decade in $\vec e(\vec n, e')X$ deep inelastic scattering.

Answer (score 2):

The "wave equation" you write has wavelike solutions of the form
$$B = \vec{B}_0 f(\vec{k}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega t)\ , $$
where $B_0$ is an amplitude in some vector direction, $\vec{K}$ is a wave-vector and $\omega$ an angular frequency and $f$ can be any sensible function (sine, cosine etc.).

By substituting this back into your wave equation you should be able to convince yourself, that this can *only* be a solution if
$$\frac{\omega}{k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_0 \epsilon_0}}\ .$$
That is, the wave speed is some physical constant that we call the speed of light.